# Running a program on Google Cloud

Tags: virtual-machine, google-cloud-storage, bioinformatics, bayesian

The program that I want to run, in particular, is [mrbayes](http://mrbayes.sourceforge.net).

I have set my project up, set up a VM instance (mrbayestest) and accessed it via terminal. I have uploaded the necessary mrbayes files to google storage and cd'd into the directory.

eg. I am at: markramotowski@mrbayestest:~/mrBayesData/mrbayes/mrbayes_3.2.2

It says that I am meant to run ./configure, but what does this mean I have to do in the VM instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you who come here looking for a similar answer for mrbayes:

this [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/mrbayes/mailman/message/28945162/) has the information to get it up and running.

essentially type:

```
sudo apt-get install mrbayes-mpi
```

into the command line.

Comment: in google cloud with ubuntu nproc gaves me 4. but mrbayes-mpi gives me 1 processor available